# Endpoint responding with not enough space

Tags: c#, .net

I'm getting:

> "System.IO.Exception not enough space"

from my endpoint on certain return objects. If debugged the code leaves the return command without any error. As far as I could analyze this it seems that there is a connection to how many objects are returned. On requests with just a few results I'm getting a proper response. My assumption is that this is caused by to many cycles in the objects. I already tried to limit the results with `.Take(x)` but this also didn't help. Please don't be to harsh this is some of my first code on this project and into .NET backend coding, and I hadn't the time or will to rework this properly.

I've also already added:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

The endpoint:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Search_Ticket_Term(string term,CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    try
    {
        var systypes = await _Context.SystemTypes.ToListAsync();
        List<RT_System> systems = new();
        systypes = systypes.Where(x => x.Localized_Name.Contains(term,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || x.Aliase.Contains(term,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
        if (systypes.Count() > 0)
            systypes = _Context.SystemTypes.Where(x => systypes.Select(y => y.SystemTypeId).Contains(x.SystemTypeId))
                .Include(c => c.TicketCategories)
                .Include(d => d.Systems)
                .Include(e=>e.Queue)
                .ToList();
        List<SystemType> systypes2 = new();
        switch(cultureInfo.ToString())
        {
            case "de-CH":
            default:
                var query2 = query.Where(x => x.Systems.Any(y => EF.Functions.Like(y.Name, "%" + term + "%")));
                if (query2.Count() > 0)
                    systypes2 = await query2.ToListAsync();
                break;
            case "fr-CH":
                var query3 = query.Where(x => x.Systems.Any(y => EF.Functions.Like(y.Name_frCH, "%" + term + "%")));
                if (query3.Count() > 0)
                    systypes2 = await query3.ToListAsync();
                break;
            case "it-CH":
                var query4 = query.Where(x => x.Systems.Any(y => EF.Functions.Like(y.Name_itCH, "%" + term + "%")));
                if (query4.Count() > 0)
                    systypes2 = await query4.ToListAsync();
                break;
        }                
        if (systypes.Count() == 0 && systypes2.Count() == 0)
            return NotFound();
        systypes = systypes.Union(systypes2).ToList();
        systypes = systypes.OrderBy(x => x.TicketCategories.Max(c => c.TicketCategoryId)).ToList();
        return Ok(systypes);
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return e.GetErrResponse();
    }

}
```

These are the returned objects.

```
[Table("TicketType", Schema = "LITS")]
public class TicketType
{
    [Column("ID_TicketType")]
    public int TicketTypeId { get; set; }
    [Column("TicketType_Bez")]
    public string Name
    { get; set; }
    [Column("TicketType_Bez_it-CH")]
    public string Name_itCH { get; set; }
    [Column("TicketType_Bez_fr-CH")]
    public string Name_frCH { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Localized_Name
    {
        get
        {
            switch (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString())
            {
                case "it-CH":
                    return Name_itCH;
                case "fr-CH":
                    return Name_frCH;
                default:
                    return Name;
            }
        }
    }
    public ICollection<TicketCategory> TicketCategories { get; set; }
}
public class TicketCategory
{
    [Column("ID_TicketCategory")]
    public int TicketCategoryId { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^((?!Select).)*$", ErrorMessage = "Select a Value")]
    [Column("TicketCategory_Bez")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column("TicketCategory_Bez_it-CH")]
    public string Name_itCH { get; set; }
    [Column("TicketCategory_Bez_fr-CH")]
    public string Name_frCH { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Localized_Name
    {
        get
        {
            switch (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString())
            {
                case "it-CH":
                    return Name_itCH;
                case "fr-CH":
                    return Name_frCH;
                default:
                    return Name;
            }
        }
    }
    public ICollection<SystemType> SystemTypes { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ICollection<TicketType> TicketTypes { get; set; }
}
public class SystemType
{
    [Column("ID_SystemType")]
    public int SystemTypeId { get; set; }
    [Column("SystemType_Bez")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^((?!Select).)*$", ErrorMessage = "Select a Value")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column("SystemType_Bez_it-CH")]
    public string Name_itCH { get; set; }
    [Column("Bereich_ID")]
    public RT_Queue Queue { get; set; }
    [Column("SystemType_Bez_fr-CH")]
    public string Name_frCH { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Localized_Name
    {
        get
        {
            switch (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString())
            {
                case "it-CH":
                    return Name_itCH;
                case "fr-CH":
                    return Name_frCH;
                default:
                    return Name;
            }
        }
    }
    public string Aliase { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RT_System> Systems { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ICollection<TicketCategory> TicketCategories { get; set; }
}
public class RT_System
{
    [Column("ID_System")]
    [Key]
    public int SystemId { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^((?!Select).)*$", ErrorMessage = "Select a Value")]
    [Column("System_Bez")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column("System_Bez_it-CH")]
    public string Name_itCH { get; set; }
    [Column("System_Bez_fr-CH")]
    public string Name_frCH { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Localized_Name
    {
        get
        {
            switch (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString())
            {
                case "it-CH":
                    return Name_itCH;
                case "fr-CH":
                    return Name_frCH;
                default:
                    return Name;
            }
        }
    }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ICollection<SystemType> SystemTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Exception:

```
System.IO.IOException: Es steht nicht genug Speicherplatz auf dem Datenträger zur Verfügung. : 'C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Temp\ASPNETCORE_e09bd0d6-8f99-4a1f-9fde-ea642b627df4.tmp'
   at System.IO.FileStream.WriteCore(ReadOnlySpan`1 source)
   at System.IO.FileStream.WriteSpan(ReadOnlySpan`1 source)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.PagedByteBuffer.MoveTo(Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingWriteStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.HttpResponseStreamWriter.Write(Char value)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter.WritePropertyName(String name, Boolean escape)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Support_Dashbord.Startup.<>c.<<Configure>b__10_0>d.MoveNext() in Startup.cs:line 172
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Please paste the full exception message

Comment: added exception message

Comment: Could be a network quota of some kind.  How are you hosting this?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro this is in my local dev environment

Comment: what are you writing? It simply means your hardisk is full try this Click Start, type %temp% in the search box and hit enter. delete everything in there

Comment: @Alander apparently the ControllerBase.Ok() method is writing a Json and I have more than 100 GB space left.

Answer (score 0):

It seems switching from NewtonSoft to System.Text.Json did the trick.
I'm not sure but it seems that [JsonIgnore] as DateAnnotation for the classes is beeing ignored by NewtonSoft.